# SSIS datetime trucation error

Tags: datetime, ssis, truncation

I'm using following expression in Derived Column Component to get hour and minute from datetime field. e.g. Get  "12:13"   from  "2012-08-14 12:13:03.650"

> LKPStartTime:
>   (DT_STR,5,1252)SUBSTRING((DT_STR,10,1252)(DT_DBTIME)StartTime,1,5)

However, it pops up error message of

> "Derived Column" failed because truncation occurred, and the
>   truncation row disposition on output column "LKPStartTime" specifies
>   failure on truncation. "

Is there any problem of my expression? Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be 12,5 instead of 1,5